# VBA run-time error 3004 when trying to mass download images form excel table

Tags: vba, excel

I got a huge excel table from manufacturer with VBA program with you can download all images from URL's in the table. When starting download it says run-time error '3004' write to file failed.

In debugger it says that this is the problem

```
oStream.SaveToFile strordner & "\" & Name, 2  ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite
```

Comment: Have you checked that the folder you are saving into actually exists?

Comment: Yes and it exist but the program during download (or rather before it) creates another folder within selected folder and names it "Export28-06-17 12H04M40S" and what I didn't say in my original question is that download actually starts and it downloads approximately 40 pictures and then the error appears.

Comment: Ok in that case I don't know why you get the error, sorry.

Comment: can you show us all of your code ?

Comment: Here's the code https://pastebin.com/XYf2p0Bn

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me that my file path had some characters that Windows doesn't accept like chr(10). After replacing that for other (like "-") it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

1. Are You sure that oStream is not empty - maybe there was some other error to Your code and now You try to save sth what is empty to file?
2. Does the place You want to save exists?
3. You choose the mode overwrite, so maybe the file that You want to overwrite is opened somewhere?